How do I merge DF's in a For Loop, as a new DF - Pandas?
I want to load new files from a folder, and then clean and combine them as one DF. I have tried pd.concat , df.join and merge(). How I can't seem to get it to do it to the two separate files/df's how do I get it to write each as new DF names
I tried a few functions, can't seem to merge as I don't know the individual DF names and I want to add new files each time I run the script.
import pandas as pd 
import os 
import glob 
from pathlib import Path
 
# assign directory
directory = "/lakehouse/default/Files/SP/SP_Xlsx/"
 
# iterate over files in
# that directory
files = Path(directory).glob('*')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='Option')


    print(file)

    # drops rows with ID: 0,1,2,3
    idx = [0,1,2,3]
    df = df.query("index != @idx")
   
    #resets Row ID 0 as index/header
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
   
    df = df.drop(df.index.to_list()[1:], axis=0)
    display(df)

The result of this is 2 data frames (both named df) how to I merge them as one?



From you code I'll guess the column names are located in row with index 4, right? If so, there is an option for that pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='Option', header=4).

yes that's correct, I was dropping the first 3 and then resetting the header, or trying to! I will try this method too, thanks!

Have included it in my answer already (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78874320/15330539). There, I'm also wondering about df.drop(df.index.to_list()[1:], axis=0), but check out my answer. Also don't forget to accept the answer which solves your question.

You can declare an empty list to store the dataframes while looping, so something like this could help. Hope I understood your question.
import pandas as pd 
import os 
import glob 
from pathlib import Path

# assign directory
directory = "/lakehouse/default/Files/SP/SP_Xlsx/"

# create an empty list to store data frames
data_frames = []

# iterate over files in that directory
files = Path(directory).glob('*')
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Option')

    print(file)

    # drops rows with ID: 0,1,2,3
    idx = [0,1,2,3]
    df = df.query("index != @idx")
   
    # resets Row ID 0 as index/header
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
   
    df = df.drop(df.index.to_list()[1:], axis=0)
    
    # append the data frame to the list
    data_frames.append(df)

# concatenate all data frames in the list
merged_df = pd.concat(data_frames, axis=0)

# display the merged data frame
display(merged_df)


Thanks, this is very much what I have been trying to do but I keep getting errors, I did have that empty df [], Im seeing this error: ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='columns'. Does the indenting have an bearing on the outcome?

Use pandas.concat as suggested by Kim Hyun Bin. In addition:

directly specify the header column with the column names by pd.read_excel(..., header=4).
I removed: df.drop(df.index.to_list()[1:], axis=0) which drops everything but the first row - or is this what you want to do? If so, you could use pd.read_excel(..., nrows=1) or df_i = df_i.iloc[:1] for simplification instead.

Providing the original excel files would help to reproduce the error and ultimately find the issue.
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 

# assign directory
directory = "/lakehouse/default/Files/SP/SP_Xlsx/"

df_list = []
for file in Path(directory).glob('*'):
    # print(file)
    df_i = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Option', header=4, 
                         nrows=1,
                         )
    
    # pre-processing the df_i, e.g.:
    # df_i['file'] = file  # to get the source of each row
    # df_i['index_org'] = df.index  # to keep the original index

    df_list.append(df_i)

# concat + indexes should be unique
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
display(df)


yes I wanted to drop all but that single row, but appreciate the options on how to achieve that.

Ok, as I wrote, use the nrow=1 parameter in pd.read. This will also speed up your code, because it reads only the first row instead of reading the whole file and drop the most of it afterwards. Included it also in my solution. Also don't forget to accept the answer which solves your question!
